# Git commit is creating unnecessary file. How to stop it?

Tags: git, git-bash

When I execute `git commit` in Git Bash, it always pops up a message:

`\Documents\revision_control\reflection\ -w does not exists. Create it?`

[image: error popup]

What is wrong with my Git Bash? Is it due to some configuration that was accidentally changed? I'm sure there's nothing called `-w` in the staging area. See output of `git status` below:

```
On branch master
Initial commit
Changes to be committed:
(use "git rm --cached ..." to unstage)

    new file:   test.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the .gitconfig file in my home directory.

It has the following line:

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -n -w
```

removing the -w solves this issue